# Avoid Google invisible recaptcha by disabling JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, submit, invisible-recaptcha

I am about to integrate the new invisible Google recaptcha to our web projects. I have a fundamental question about the functionality of web bots. It may sounds silly but do they definitely need to use JavaScript like a real user / humans do?

For example: When I test my html submit form with JavaScript is enabled, the Google recaptcha functionality works fine and the site stays unchanged / not submitted (removed my Google Key for test reasons). But when I do the same with JavaScript is disabled the form is execute without any recaptcha check.

So can I expect that bots that are visit my site always will use JavaScript so they are not able to skip the Google recaptcha mechanism by disable JavaScript or something? Or did I Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It may sounds silly but do they definitely need to use JavaScript like a real user / humans do?

Yes (i.e. They don't. They may support JS. They may not support JS.)

> So can I expect that bots that are visit my site always will use JavaScript

No

> so they are not able to skip the Google recaptcha mechanism by disable JavaScript or something?

Disabling JS doesn't allow recaptcha to be skipped. If the JS doesn't run, then the extra field doesn't get added so when you [verify the user's response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) on your server: it will fail.

Comment: Stupid me, I forgot about the response verification on the server. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: This also means that a human visitor with JavaScript disabled will experience a form failure. Not sure what I can do to prevent that.